# How to make the content area to take up full width of its max-width

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I got a CSS grid that looks like this,

`full-start | wide-start | content-start | content-end | wide-end | full-end`

What I want it to do:

- I'm trying to make it so the content area would always have it's max-width, it has a maximium width of 77rem (1232px). While the screen shrinks wide should also shrink accordingly and eventually wide and content will catch up to each other if that make sense? So Wide should shrink "first" because again they will eventually catch up.

What's happening now:

- "wide" is always at it's "max" and does not shrink at all. I would like for "content" to keep its max-width all times and "wide" to shrink first.

SUMMARY:
I would it like that "content" keep its max-width and "wide" shrink first.

[image]

```css
.my-grid {
  --const-content: 77rem;
  --const-max-inline-size: 90rem;
  
  --gutter: 4rem;
  --content: minmax(0, var(--const-content));
  --wide: minmax(0, calc((var(--const-max-inline-size) - var(--const-content)) / 2));
  --max-inline-size: calc(var(--const-max-inline-size) + (var(--gutter) * 2));
    
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [full-start] var(--gutter) 
                         [wide-start] var(--wide) 
                         [content-start] var(--content) [content-end] 
                         var(--wide) [wide-end] 
                         var(--gutter) [full-end];
  max-inline-size: var(--max-inline-size);
}

.block {
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.block--content {
  grid-column: content;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.block--wide {
  grid-column: wide;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.block--full {
  grid-column: full;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-grid">
  <div class="block block--full">full</div>
  <div class="block block--content">content</div>
  <div class="block block--wide">wide</div>
</div>
```

Comment: By center do you mean what you called "CONTENT"?

Comment: @OuttaSpaceTime good catch, yes that was a typo I corrected it.

Comment: and after they shrinked to the same size, you want them both shrink by the same portion?

Comment: @OuttaSpaceTime I'm thinking. Looking at it in the grid. Wide is 90rem and Content is 70rem. So when a viewport is 50rem Wide is 0rem and Content would be 50rem (minus the gutter of cause that is fixed width). If that makes sense?

Comment: are you obliged to use CSS grid? because I don't see the need here

Comment: @TemaniAfif The examples here are simplified, the component will be used as a container and for more complex things like building blocks where rows will be introduced.

Answer (score 1):

Not a very clear question, but if you want the `.block--content` to have a minimum width, add [`place-self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-self) to `.block--content`:

```css
.my-grid {
  --const-content: 77rem;
  --const-max-inline-size: 90rem;
  
  --gutter: 4rem;
  --content: minmax(0, var(--const-content));
  --wide: minmax(0, calc((var(--const-max-inline-size) - var(--const-content)) / 2));
  --max-inline-size: calc(var(--const-max-inline-size) + (var(--gutter) * 2));
    
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [full-start] var(--gutter) 
                         [wide-start] var(--wide) 
                         [content-start] var(--content) [content-end] 
                         var(--wide) [wide-end] 
                         var(--gutter) [full-end];
  max-inline-size: var(--max-inline-size);
}

.block {
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.block--content {
  grid-column: content;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  place-self: center; /*  */
}

.block--wide {
  grid-column: wide;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.block--full {
  grid-column: full;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-grid">
  <div class="block block--full">full</div>
  <div class="block block--content">content</div>
  <div class="block block--wide">wide</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You changed your question a lot. )) I suggest you close it and create a new one.

Comment: I didn't change my question I just made more clear to what I was asking for :)

Comment: Well, there is a history of editing: *keep->have it's minimum->max-width*. After editing, the context of the question has changed in a coordinated way. That is why I would like you to think about the following questions first, and only then formulate the questions. Best regards.

Comment: Still the question has the same intent, It's my fault I didn't manage to express my need in a better way, "keep it's minimum width" was made more clear with expressing it like max-width, if you look at the code minimum width for content is 0 so the question would not make any sense at all if wanting the minimum width :). Also this was a tricky question to formulate.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need CSS grid to do this. Check this link to understand how the `margin-inline` is working: https://css-tip.com/center-max-width/

```css
.my-grid {
  --const-content: 77rem;
  --const-max-inline-size: 90rem;  
  --gutter: 4rem;

  max-inline-size: calc(var(--const-max-inline-size) + 2*var(--gutter));
  margin: auto;
}

.block {
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.block--content {
  margin-inline: max(var(--gutter), 50% - var(--const-content)/2);
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.block--wide {
  margin-inline: max(var(--gutter), 50% - var(--const-max-inline-size)/2);
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.block--full {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-grid">
  <div class="block block--full">full</div>
  <div class="block block--content">content</div>
  <div class="block block--wide">wide</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I used this for a navigation I did a while back, got it from one of your tweets :). For this specific component I would benefit greatly if I could pull it off with grid. Even a solution with having just the area "Wide", and center content in it and use max-inline-size on `block--content` is not optimal.